# How do I insert data from a view into a table using a cloud function or some automated trigger.

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I can do this in the GUI by using the save as table button. I am trying find a way to automate this to run either on a daily schedule or triggered when a file lands.

Any ideas?

Comment: One option is to sign up for the [scheduled query alpha](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeHQuU0KrWv1Wc4DbXSTZf1aw7_VWUiGIJQ7B-Mwshbtfs8cA/viewform). This would let you schedule the queries directly from BigQuery itself. Other people may have solutions that don't require using an alpha feature, though.

Comment: don't you have already your answer in yours very question? - Cloud Functions!!!

Comment: Yes, but I have not figured out how to do this in cloud functions.  My knowledge of them is primitive at best.

Comment: Did you try reading the Cloud Functions documentation? If you get stuck, please provide the code that you have tried and the problem that you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

"Simplest way to schedule BigQuery jobs: Copy this sheet, customize, create trigger for any day/time":

-
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JZkkKcT9yrcYc1g8QqJaIE6PJtoFig3G_ZNbtXuK6fw/edit#gid=0

Basically it uses Apps Script to call a query stored in a sheet during regular intervals. You can customize!

Source: https://twitter.com/anilopez/status/958382085407883264

Comment: Very interesting.  Where do you use the code? is there any detailed documentation for how to use this?

Comment: see https://shinesolutions.com/2017/11/01/scheduling-bigquery-jobs-using-google-apps-script/, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery